# C# desktop app - run another application within a window or frame

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application (although would happily move to unity or something like that if required) that needs to remain on the right hand third of the screen while open.  From that application I am running external applications (for eg notepad/calculator), and when they are maximised, they need to only maximise to the remaining 2 thirds.  Is this possible?